# Adding ribbon to Window Explorer in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-explorer

Is there any app that modifies Windows 7 Windows explorer and make it similar to Windows 8 ribbon style or is there any app that provide Windows 8 explorer function and style to windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do this:

http://www.intowindows.com/windows-8-ribbon-ui-in-windows-explorer/

There is a tool called [Styler](ftp://ftp.crystalxp.net/crystalxp.net/63677/en/1/styler-1-401-crystalxp.net-551.zip). Install it in XP compatibility mode, enable the **Styler Toolbar** and apply this [skin](http://peterrollar.deviantart.com/art/Windows8-ribbon-UI-for-styler-216205055?).

There is also a 3rd party tool called [BetterExplorer](http://better-explorer.com/). Try both solution and use the one you like more.

Comment: Better Explorer is so slow

Comment: @Magnetic_dud Thanks, which one are more stable? Do you used any one before?

Comment: Better Explorer is slow because it is a WPF application.

Comment: I only used Better Explorer, but I could not bear waiting 3-4 seconds to its startup. I think the Styler solution is great - now I am using Windows 8, so I don't need it anymore

Comment: @Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately non of them run on my 64B win7.

Answer (score 2):

there is an application that fully replaces your Explorer - With the Windows 8 look! 
link: http://better-explorer.com

Answer (score -1):

Classic Shell lets you get what you want!
http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/ ;)

Comment: I think you read the question wrong.